# ruby: what does the asterisk in "p *1..10" mean

Tags: ruby, operators, range

the line

```
p *1..10
```

does exactly the same thing as

```
(1..10).each { |x| puts x }
```

which gives you the following output:

```
$ ruby -e "p *1..10"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

it's a great shortcut when working with textmate for example, but what does the asterisk do? how does that work? couldn't find anything on the net...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's the [splat operator](http://theplana.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/ruby-idioms-the-splat-operator/). You'll often see it used to split an array into parameters to a function.

```
def my_function(param1, param2, param3)
  param1 + param2 + param3
end

my_values = [2, 3, 5]

my_function(*my_values) # returns 10
```

More commonly it is used to accept an arbitrary number of arguments

```
def my_other_function(to_add, *other_args)
  other_args.map { |arg| arg + to_add }
end

my_other_function(1, 6, 7, 8) # returns [7, 8, 9]
```

It also works for multiple assignment (although both of these statements will work without the splat):

```
first, second, third = *my_values
*my_new_array = 7, 11, 13
```

For your example, these two would be equivalent:

```
p *1..10
p 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Comment: i seems to me that    a, b, c = *myvalues
is equivalent to      a, b, c = myvalues

or is ruby implicitly using the splat operator in this case?

Comment: @Patrick Yes, assignment where there is one object on one side and multiple objects on the other will sort of imply a splat operator. So that's not a very useful example, I guess.