# Behavior of the '*' operator in Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am a newbie in Ruby. Please explain how the * operator works in this case.

```
arr = [1,2,3]
p arr
arr = *[1,2,3]
p arr
*arr = [1,2,3]
p arr
arr = [1,2,3]
p *arr
```

OUTPUT

[1,2,3]

[1,2,3]

[1,2,3]

1

2

3

What is happening in the last case ? Is it behaving as a iterator ? Can anyone give an example as to how to use it ? 
Also why it has no effect in the second and third case ?

Comment: Same question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729284/ruby-what-does-the-asterisk-in-p-1-10-mean

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the \* (star) mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170037/what-does-the-star-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

The "*" operator on an array in that context, turns an array into a list of arguments.

Let's say you have a method that takes three arguments:

```
def takes_three(one, two, three)
  puts "first: #{one}, second: #{two}, third: #{three}"
end
```

If you tried to do this:

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
takes_three(arr)
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)
```

Your method takes three arguments, but you only passed it one -- that one was an array.

If you want to turn the array of three elements into three separate arguments to the method, that's what `*` does here:

```
takes_three(*arr)
# => puts "first: a, second: b, third: c"
```

What gets confusing in your examples, believe it or not, is your use of `p`, shortcut in irb for `puts`. `puts` takes a variable number of arguments, you can give it however many you want. It will output them all, separated by newlines. And if you give it a single array argument, it will still output each element in the array separated by newlines.

```
irb(main):068:0> puts ["a", "b", "c"]
a
b
c
irb(main):069:0> puts "a", "b", "c"
a
b
c
irb(main):070:0> puts arr
a
b
c
irb(main):071:0> puts *arr
a
b
c
```

Since `puts "a", "b", "c"` and `puts ["a", "b", "c"]` do the same thing, `puts arr` and `puts *arr` do the same thing too. Since `puts *arr` is equivalent to `puts 1, 2, 3`, it expands an array into separate arguments for the method.

So your attempt to investigate with `puts` makes it confusing, because `puts` takes a variable number of arguments, and does the same thing with one argument that's an array of n elements, as it does with n separate arguments each of those elements. Most methods don't work that way though, so for most methods `*`, changing the nature of the arguments you're giving to the method, will also change what the method does.  It is useful for a kind of indirection, where you build up the arguments you want to pass in an array dynamically, instead of writing them fixed in source code.

Answer (score 0):

That is the **splat operator**  (*). It can be used to expand the array in a method call to list of argument or in some assignment to to a 'take all'. Below is some example:

**1) Using pass array to method call as list of arguments**

Given the following method:

```
def my_method(argument1, argument2, argument3)
end
```

You can turn an Array into an argument list with * (or splat) operator:

```
arguments = [1, 2, 3]
my_method(*arguments)
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html

**2) using with assignment to to 'take all'**

*, sometimes called the "splat operator," does a number of things with arrays. When it's on the left side of an assignment operator (=), as in your example, it just means "take everything left over."

Example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
head, *tail = a
p head #=> 1
p tail #=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you omitted the splat in that code, it would do this instead:

```
head, tail = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
p head # => 1
p tail # => 2
```

But when you add the splat to tail it means "Everything that didn't get assigned to the previous variables (head), assign to tail."

**source:** 
[What does this mean in Ruby language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618697/what-does-this-mean-in-ruby-language?rq=1)